# How to simplify javascript nested array with map(), reduce(), and filter()?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

First of all I am a newbie into Javascript, ES6 etc and I come from Java background. 
I have a complex javascript array structure (example given below),
I am trying to convert this array into a map (similar to how Java has, key value pair kind of thing), key being the permission names (e.g KEY-1, KEY-2, KEY-3, KEY-4,KEY-5 with regards to the javascript array example below) while value being the comma separated values of the actual permission. I can achieve it by looping b thru the nested arrays, but loop is what I am trying to avoid here and wanted to do using map()/reduce()/filter()

Here is an example of how the map should contain the data. Since KEY-2 is present in both the arrays, they will be overridden into one (which is perfectly fine)

```
KEY-1 = ["Roles.Create","Roles.Edit"]
KEY-2 = ["API-Admin.Create","API-Admin.Edit","API-Admin.Read"]
KEY-3 = ["Roles.Create","Roles.Edit"]
KEY-4 = ["Users.Read"]      
KEY-5 = ["Roles.Create","Roles.Edit"]
```

### Javascript Array

```
const teamArr = [
  {
    "name":"Team1",
    "accountId":"Billing",
    "teamId":"12345",
    "permissions": {
        "KEY-1": [
            "Roles.Create",
            "Roles.Edit"
        ],
        "KEY-2": [
            "API-Admin.Create",
            "API-Admin.Edit",
            "API-Admin.Read"
        ],
        "KEY-3": [
          "Roles.Create",
          "Roles.Edit"
        ]
     }
   },
   {
     "name":"Team2",
     "accountId":"Sales",
     "teamId":"6789",
     "permissions": {
         "KEY-4": [
             "Users.Read"
         ],
         "KEY-2": [
            "API-Admin.Create",
            "API-Admin.Edit",
            "API-Admin.Read"
        ],
         "KEY-5": [
           "Roles.Create",
           "Roles.Edit"
         ]
      }
   }
]
```

KEY-1, KEY-2,KEY-3,KEY-4, KEY-5 etc are all dynamically generated, so I CAN NOT hardcode these keys names into my code (like KEY-1, KEY-2 etc.)

I followed this post https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/15-useful-javascript-examples-of-map-reduce-and-filter-74cbbb5e0a1f/
and below is what I tried but I guess, I am struggling to properly use sort()/reduce() properly on a complex javascript array. I would prefer plain Javascript/ES6 solution (no JQuery pls).

```
const sorted = test.sort((a, b) => a.permissions - b.permissions);
// Using reduce:
dict = sorted.reduce(
    (dict, el, index) => (dict[el.permissions] = sorted.length - index, dict),
    {}
);

console.log(dict)
```

Any help here would highly be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't need to worry about the other keys/values, you need to firstly create an array of all the `permissions` objects. Then you extract the properties from that array, keeping the arrays unique with Sets:

```js
const teamArr = [{"name":"Team1","accountId":"Billing","teamId":"12345","permissions":{"KEY-1":["Roles.Create","Roles.Edit"],"KEY-2":["API-Admin.Create","API-Admin.Edit","API-Admin.Read"],"KEY-3":["Roles.Create","Roles.Edit"]}},{"name":"Team2","accountId":"Sales","teamId":"6789","permissions":{"KEY-4":["Users.Read"],"KEY-2":["API-Admin.Create","API-Admin.Edit","API-Admin.Read"],"KEY-5":["Roles.Create","Roles.Edit"]}}];
const res = teamArr.flatMap(({ permissions }) => Object.entries(permissions)).reduce((a, [k, v]) => ((a[k] = [...new Set(((a[k] = a[k] || []).push(...v), a[k]))], a)), {});
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

More verbose version:

```js
const teamArr = [{"name":"Team1","accountId":"Billing","teamId":"12345","permissions":{"KEY-1":["Roles.Create","Roles.Edit"],"KEY-2":["API-Admin.Create","API-Admin.Edit","API-Admin.Read"],"KEY-3":["Roles.Create","Roles.Edit"]}},{"name":"Team2","accountId":"Sales","teamId":"6789","permissions":{"KEY-4":["Users.Read"],"KEY-2":["API-Admin.Create","API-Admin.Edit","API-Admin.Read"],"KEY-5":["Roles.Create","Roles.Edit"]}}];
const permissions = teamArr.map(({ permissions }) => permissions);
const res = permissions.flatMap(Object.entries).reduce((a, [k, v]) => {
  a[k] = a[k] || [];
  a[k].push(...v);
  a[k] = [...new Set(a[k])];
  return a;
}, {});
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Comment: Thanks Jack. Your both the solutions worked like a charm. Really appreciate your help here.

Comment: No problem @JameelKhan, always glad to help. If my answer fixed your problem, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a combination of [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and `reduce` (although `flatMap` isn't supported on all browsers yet):

```js
const teamArr = [{
    "name": "Team1",
    "accountId": "Billing",
    "teamId": "12345",
    "permissions": {
      "KEY-1": [
        "Roles.Create",
        "Roles.Edit"
      ],
      "KEY-2": [
        "API-Admin.Create",
        "API-Admin.Edit",
        "API-Admin.Read"
      ],
      "KEY-3": [
        "Roles.Create",
        "Roles.Edit"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Team2",
    "accountId": "Sales",
    "teamId": "6789",
    "permissions": {
      "KEY-4": [
        "Users.Read"
      ],
      "KEY-2": [
        "API-Admin.Create",
        "API-Admin.Edit",
        "API-Admin.Read"
      ],
      "KEY-5": [
        "Roles.Create",
        "Roles.Edit"
      ]
    }
  }
]

const result = teamArr
  .flatMap(t => Object.entries(t.permissions))
  .reduce((acc, [key, permissions]) => {
    acc[key] = acc[key] || [];
    acc[key].push(...permissions.filter(p => !acc[key].includes(p)));
    return acc;
  }, {});
  
console.log(result);
```

If the permissions array for a key can be very big, you can also consider using a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) next to each key in the accumulator.

Comment: Thanks slider, appreciate your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
const teamArr = [
  {
    "name":"Team1",
    "accountId":"Billing",
    "teamId":"12345",
    "permissions": {
        "KEY-1": [
            "Roles.Create",
            "Roles.Edit"
        ],
        "KEY-2": [
            "API-Admin.Create",
            "API-Admin.Edit",
            "API-Admin.Read"
        ],
        "KEY-3": [
          "Roles.Create",
          "Roles.Edit"
        ]
     }
   },
   {
     "name":"Team2",
     "accountId":"Sales",
     "teamId":"6789",
     "permissions": {
         "KEY-4": [
             "Users.Read"
         ],
         "KEY-2": [
            "API-Admin.Create",
            "API-Admin.Edit",
            "API-Admin.Read"
        ],
         "KEY-5": [
           "Roles.Create",
           "Roles.Edit"
         ]
      }
   }
];



function extractPermissions(obj) {
    const perms = {};
    obj.forEach(entry => {
        if (!entry['permissions']) {
            return;
        }
        Object.keys(entry.permissions).forEach(key => {
            if (!perms[key]) {
                perms[key] = [];
            }
            entry.permissions[key].forEach(value => {
                if (!perms[key].some(val => val === value)) {
                    perms[key].push(value);
                }
            });
        });
    });
    return perms;
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(extractPermissions(teamArr), null, 2));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help René Datenschutz. The only thing is that the solution uses loops which is what I was trying to avoid, but I guess this is using plain vanilla JS/ES6, it wont have any browser version dependency. Nonetheless, appreciate your help here :-)